# Linq Grouping in VB.net with anonymous types and option strict

Tags: vb.net, linq

Trying to do something I'm sure should be simple, but struggling with linq and VB. I've got the below, where I'm grouping a collection by a propery, then wanting to access the properties of my group. Problem I have is with the anonymous typing. Because of option strict I have to give an explicit type but I can't work out what the type should be. The below doesn't compile because t.HeadAccountKey isn't a value (as t has a type of object). So either I need do some casting or my linq selector is wrong,

```
public class TempObject
    public HeadKey as string
    Public SubKey as string
    Public SomeValue as decimal
end class

public class GroupTest
public sub RunTest
    dim collection new List(of TempObject) = GetTestCollection()

    Dim groupedValues As IEnumerable = From n In collection _
        Group By key = n.HeadKey Into Group Select HeadKeyValue = key, SubValues = Group

    for each t as object in groupedValues
    debug.print(t.HeadKeyValue)
        next

End sub

private function GetTestCollection() as List(of TempObject)
    dim result as new list(of tempobject)
    Dim x As New tempObject
    x.HeadAccountNumber = "A"
        x.SubAccountNumber = "B"
        x.Value = 500
        result.Add(x)
        x = New tempObject
        x.HeadAccountNumber = "A"
        x.SubAccountNumber = "C"
        x.Value = 600
        result.Add(x)
        x = New tempObject
        x.HeadAccountNumber = "B"
        x.SubAccountNumber = "D"
        x.Value = 100
    result.add(x)
    return result
end function
End class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type, at least with [`Option Infer on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx)(recommendable, not to be confused with `Option Strict`).

So following works:

```
Dim collection = GetTestCollection()
Dim groupedValues = From n In collection
    Group n By n.HeadKey Into Group

For Each t In groupedValues
    Dim hk = t.HeadKey
    Dim group = t.Group
Next
```